# ddev v1.3.0 has MariaDB 10.2 which can be incompatible with TYPO3 v8

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, ddev

I noted in the upgrade of ddev v1.3.0 that it uses MariaDB 10.2, which has compatibility problems with TYPO3 v8.

Answer (score 2):

Edit 2019-01-08: As of ddev v1.5.0 you can configure the version of MariaDB you want; 10.1 is available. Use `mariadb_version: "10.1"` in *.ddev/config.yaml*. Note that if you already have the project up using 10.2 you'll need to `ddev rm --remove-data` to get a fresh database with 10.1.

Many TYPO3 community members were excited to get MariaDB 10.2... but oops, sorry for breaking those with projects on TYPO3 v8.  We hope to resolve this with more options in an upcoming release.

In the meantime, you can:

- Use ddev v1.2.0 or
- Just use the db container from v1.2.0 by adding `dbimage: drud/ddev-dbserver:v1.2.0` to the *.ddev/config.yaml* of your TYPO3 v8.7 project.

For updates, follow [this issue in the ddev queue](https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1221)
Details on the incompatibilities of MariaDB 10.2 and TYPO3 v8.7 are at https://github.com/davdenic/typo3-ddev-project-setup